# Undefined variable: in laravel function

Tags: php, laravel-4, controller

Can any one tell me why i am getting error for the following code.

```
public function postFormfilehandellerpre(){
        $event = Input::get('event');

        if($event =="Rescom Summit Bangalore 2015")
        $qid1 = "3124";

        $users = User::where('event','=',$event)->orderby('name')->with(array('answer'=>function($q){
            $q->where('question_id','=',$qid1)->orWhere('question_id','=',$qid1+1);
        }))->get();


        return Redirect::to('admin/formfilehandellerpre')->with(array('liusers'=>$users,'liev'=>$event));
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
Undefined variable: qid1
```

Then i tried to pass the $qid inside the function like this

```
$users = User::where('event','=',$event)->orderby('name')->with(array('answer'=>function($q,$qid1){
            $q->where('question_id','=',$qid1)->orWhere('question_id','=',$qid1+1);
        }))->get();
```

**ERROR**

```
Missing argument 2 for AdminController::{closure}()
```

Comment: I think it should be `'answer' => function() use($q, $qid1) {`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois oh yeah right let me try this ,

Comment: Yes it works It just didnt pass my mind :(, You can post as an answer I will accept it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use laravel but if you expect them as parameter laravel doesn't know that, which is why you have to use

```
function() use($expected, $parameters) {
```

In your case it is

```
function() use($q, $qid1) {
```